# Is it appropriate to do an ANOVA on a feature selected via inspecting PCA results?

Tags: anova, pca, multiple-comparisons, exploratory-data-analysis

I've been given a dataset consisting of 8 dimensional feature vectors for 4 classes of objects. I was asked to find the features that best distinguish the classes, and write up a short report.

My first instinct was to do a PCA on the data. This yielded the following plot, among others.

[image]

From visual inspection, it seems that the squares have higher 8000 Hz values than the other symbols.

My next instinct, on seeing this trend, was to do a one-way ANOVA on the 8 kHz feature, followed by a Tukey HSD test, to reassure myself that the difference between classes was significant. These test came to mind not because I know them to be appropriate, but rather because they're the only tests I'm familiar with. I have no idea whether or not they're well suited to this context.

My questions: is an ANOVA, followed by a planned comparison, the right course of action here? Or would some other test be more appropriate?

Comment: Why are you plotting components 3 and 4, rather than 1 and 2?

Comment: The trend was more visually apparent in the pc 34 plot. I know that the 12 plot explains more variance.

Comment: You have multi-dimensional data.  It sounds like you'd want to do a MANOVA here to look for differences.

Comment: Why don't you simply run an ANOVA for each of your 8 variables? If you are reluctant to do so because of the multiple comparisons issue, then looking at all the PCs is *also* kind of a multiple comparisons situation. So if after looking at the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and 4th PCs you decide to test variable 8000Hz and obtain some significant p-value, it can be argued to be cherry picking and you would still need somehow to take multiple comparisons into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have 8 features in your data, it is not so many. The simplest approach is to conduct 8 ANOVAs, one for each feature, and correct for multiple comparisons with e.g. Bonferroni or Holm-Bonferroni correction.

If you had 8000 features, then this would probably result in no feature being significant, and one would need to think about more suitable approaches, but with 8 features you can safely start with simple ANOVAs.

Crucially, your PCA analysis can not be considered as a way out of the multiple comparisons problem. If you had decided to test your 8000Hz feature *a priori*, then you would not have needed to use a Bonferroni correction. But if you look at the PCA plots first, it is by definition not *a priori* anymore. You looked at the features and tried to select the "best" one; whether you did it with PCA or with conducting all possible ANOVAs is immaterial -- you have already run into the multiple comparisons territory.

Answer (score 0):

Again, my main question here is which statistical test to use to figure out which features best distinguish my classes.

@StatsStudent suggests that I do a MANOVA, since I'm investigating the effect of one independent variable - class - on multiple dependent variables. This seems reasonable but I'm unfamiliar with the procedure and don't have time to read up on it.

@amoeba suggests doing one ANOVA on each feature followed by planned comparisons. He points out that my visual analysis of the PCA is, in effect, conducting a set of multiple comparisons. If I'm going to test for effects that are visually suggested by the PCA, I'll need to be careful to control my experiment-wide $ \alpha $.

I'm going to follow @ameoba's advice and do a one way anova on the 8 kHz feature, followed by a Tukey HSD test. To keep my experiment-wide error, $ \bar{\alpha} $, below 0.05, I'll use [Bonferroni correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem).

Bonferroni correction requires setting $ \alpha_{per comparison} $ to $\bar{\alpha} / k $, where  $k$ is the number of comparisons. My PCA is doing 6 comparisons (4 classes, pairwise) on 8 features, for a total of 48 comparisons.  So $ \alpha_{per comparison} = \bar{\alpha} / k = 0.05 / 48 = 0.001 $.

Comment: If anyone sees problems in my answer above, please correct me!

Comment: First, 0.05/48 is around 0.001, not 0.01. Second, I don't understand how you arrived to the number 48. Third (and most important), doing all 8 ANOVAs would require you to divide alpha by 8, not by 48, so why wouldn't you simply do that? Use PCA only for guidance/overview/whatever, but run ANOVAs on all variables and correct for that. Fourth, Bonferroni is too conservative, use Holm–Bonferroni instead. Fifth, MANOVA is definitely not appropriate, it constructs linear combinations of original features, whereas you seem to be interested in the original features themselves.

Comment: Thank you!  I figured that the best way to get a good answer would be to write something possibly wrong and let you respond. If you write up your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. Otherwise I'll edit my answer in a day or two to align with yours.

Comment: Re: the number 48, I still feel like my visual analysis of the PCA plots is implicitly doing 48 comparisons. I'm looking for differences in 8 features (63 Hz, 125 Hz, 250 Hz, etc...) and I'm comparing four classes of objects. Pairwise comparisons of four classes means 6 comparisons, doesn't it?  (1&2, 1&3, 1&4, 2&3, 2&4, 3&4) $ 8 \times 6 = 48 $  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: :) I like your strategy. Re 48: well, this is hard to say because it depends on what exactly *you were thinking* when you looked at your PCA plots. I would guess that you looked at your various PCA plots and tried to select one "best" feature to conduct an ANOVA on. There are 8 features, so it's again 1/8.

Comment: @dB', Why, really, 48? You are selecting one or more reliably discriminating features out of 8. So, Bonferroni for 8 tests will suffice. When you come to pairwise comparisons between 6 group on the selected feature(s) - it is another family of tests and another instance of correction, because you are already relying on the selected feature as if it is only one at hand.

Comment: Here is a really good reference to peforming a MANOVA in SAS, if you have access to that software:  http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/dae/manova1.htm.